# Python Flask app insists on running on default port 5000 despite attempts to change it

Tags: python, flask, port

As the title of my question says, I tried to set the port to something other than 5000. I tried two ways:

- in app.py I did this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5001)
```

- In config.py I included the following line under class Config(object):

```
SERVER_NAME = "127.0.0.1:5001"
```

Neither worked and when I run my app I get

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**EDIT:** As an answer below has pointed out that the app.run() way of doing it seems to have been depracated, I was able to change the port by running the flask app with command line arguments. However, it would still be useful to me if I could hardcode the port in the config.py file itself. According to flask documentation, this method is still in use. But I'm not well informed on the details of using the config.py file so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I followed my teacher's sample code for that. He did the following in app.py:

```
from config import DevConfig
app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
```

(DevConfig is a subclass of Config in the config.py file)

Comment: How did you run your app?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm. I simply clicked Run.

Comment: @AndrewS. could you check how has the Run command been executed in PyCharm?

Comment: "C:\ ... \venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m flask run

Answer (score 3):

I was using the following way to specify the listenning port in the command line:

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80`

The way you used in your code (`app.run`), if I remember correctly, has been deprecated in current flask release (to use `flask run` to start the server instead of `python app.py`).

You could refer to [this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) for a general introduction.

In my understanding, the new way makes it much easier to specify different ports for various scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using PyCharm as my IDE. Do you happen to know if there's any way to automate the way the app runs with these arguments which you suggested? I know in Eclipse for Java you can edit the run configuration to specify arguments, but when I go to edit configuration in PyCharm I don't see anything about arguments or parameters...

Comment: Never mind, I found the field I was looking for. It's called "Additional options" in PyCharm. I'm able to set the arguments there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use following in end of code 
       if **name** == '**main**':
          app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
and instead of `$ flask run`
use `$ python app.py`

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for other people like me (using not only Flask , but also flask_socketio). If you run a flask_socketio app, use `python app.py` to start it, not `flask run` as would be the right way for a Flask server (not flask_socketio). I mix them up sometimes as I run both simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

For those who is using pyCharm, you need to change the configuration of the execution. In this way you may run any tasks at the same time you need. Simply add Additional options. Here is the example that I am using:

[image]

[image]

[image]